# Функция, которая работает в ассемблерной вставке, не работает в модуле на ассемблере

Tags: c++, ассемблер, visual-studio-2017

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо реализовать мультимодульную программу (ассемблер + c++), которая в матрице вычисляет сумму строк верхнего треугольника.

Мною была написана функция для выполнения данного задания на c++ (функция f), затем она была написана в ассемблерной вставке (функция f_asm), а затем она была скопирована в отдельной модуль на ассемблере (функция Fasm). Функции f и f_asm работают корректно, а Fasm во время работы выдает ошибку.

Наверное, стоит отметить, что матрица хранится в одномерном массиве, ибо мне кажется, что так в данном случае удобнее

### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "C" void Fasm(int*, int, int*);

void f(int *arr, int n, int * ans)
{
    int k = n, s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i, --k)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < k; ++j)
        {
            //ans[n - j - 1] += arr[s + k - j - 1];
            ans[n - j - 1] += arr[s + n - j - 1];
        }
        s += n;
    }
}

void f_asm(int*, int, int*)
{
    _asm {


        sub esp, 12
        mov eax, [ebp + 12]
        mov dword ptr[ebp - 4], eax; k
        mov dword ptr[ebp - 8], 0; s
        mov dword ptr[ebp - 12], 0; i
        c1 :
            mov eax, [ebp - 12]
            cmp eax, [ebp + 12]
            jge endc1
            mov ebx, 0; j
            c2 :

                cmp ebx, [ebp - 4]
                jge endc2

                mov ecx, 0
                add ecx, [ebp + 12]
                sub ecx, ebx
                dec ecx
                shl ecx, 2
                add ecx, [ebp + 16]
                mov edx, 0
                add edx, [ebp - 8]
                add edx, [ebp + 12]
                sub edx, ebx
                dec edx
                shl edx, 2
                add edx, [ebp + 8]
                mov eax, [edx]
                mov edx, eax
                add[ecx], edx

                inc ebx
                jmp c2
            endc2 :

            mov eax, [ebp - 8]
            add eax, [ebp + 12]
            mov[ebp - 8], eax

            inc dword ptr[ebp - 12]
            dec dword ptr[ebp - 4]
            jmp c1

        endc1 :
        add esp, 12

    }
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int *arr, n;
    cout << "Введите размерность матрицы: ";
    cin >> n;
    arr = new int[n*n];
    cout << "Введите матрицу:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n*n; ++i)
        cin >> arr[i];
    int *ans = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        ans[i] = 0;
    Fasm(arr, n, ans);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        cout << ans[i] << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

### module.asm

```
.586
.model flat
public _Fasm
.code
_Fasm proc
push ebp
push ebx
mov ebp, esp

sub esp, 12
mov eax, [ebp + 12]
mov dword ptr[ebp - 4], eax; k
mov dword ptr[ebp - 8], 0; s
mov dword ptr[ebp - 12], 0; i
c1 :
    mov eax, [ebp - 12]
    cmp eax, [ebp + 12]
    jge endc1
    mov ebx, 0; j
    c2 :

        cmp ebx, [ebp - 4]
        jge endc2

        mov ecx, 0
        add ecx, [ebp + 12]
        sub ecx, ebx
        dec ecx
        shl ecx, 2
        add ecx, [ebp + 16]
        mov edx, 0
        add edx, [ebp - 8]
        add edx, [ebp + 12]
        sub edx, ebx
        dec edx
        shl edx, 2
        add edx, [ebp + 8]
        mov eax, [edx]
        mov edx, eax
        add [ecx], edx

        inc ebx
        jmp c2
    endc2 :

    mov eax, [ebp - 8]
    add eax, [ebp + 12]
    mov[ebp - 8], eax

    inc dword ptr[ebp - 12]
    dec dword ptr[ebp - 4]
    jmp c1
endc1 :
add esp, 12
pop ebx
pop ebp
ret
_Fasm endp
end
```

Comment: А проект вы настраивали? https://habr.com/ru/post/252647/

Comment: Да, вроде как всё настроил. Да и на этапе компиляции проблем нет, только во время работы

Comment: Вы определитесь сначала, как у вас хранится матрица, что является строками и столбцами, и где находится этот верхний треугольник. Я запросил матрицу 5x5 и заполнил значениями 1, 2, 3, ..., 25. Ваша функция `f` выдала ответ `1 9 24 46 75`. Это каким это образом такие суммы могут быть "суммой строк верхнего треугольника"? При каком формате хранения матрицы?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Стандартный" код пролога вашей функции - это

```
push        ebp  
mov         ebp,esp  
push        ebx
```

Вы, очевидно, свои ассемблерные варианты писали не самостоятельно, а просто скопировали сгенерированный компилятором код. Однако код компилятора сгенерирован именно в расчете на вышепроцитированный пролог.

А у вас в `Fasm` пролог внезапно выглядит так

```
push ebp
push ebx
mov  ebp, esp
```

Зачем вы поменяли порядок команд? Из-за этого поменялось значение `ebp` и все скопированные из исходного варианта ссылки на параметры "поехали" вкривь и вкось.

Comment: И еще поправка: компилятор генерирует код в расчете на соблюдение функцией соглашения вызова. Как именно выглядят пролог и эпилог (и вообще есть ли они) - не имеет значения, главное чтобы соглашение вызова соблюдалось и стек не поехал.

Comment: @insolor Неверно. Как я ясно сказал выше, порядок команд влияет на значение `ebp` внутри функции. Доступ к параметрам функции изнутри функции делается имеено относительно `ebp`. В варианте `Fasm` доступ к параметрам превращается в полную чушь из-за поменявшегося значения `ebp`. А вы нам рассказываете, что он "не влияет ни на что"...

Comment: Ок, ошибся, порядок `mov` и `push` имеет значение.

Comment: @insolor Я веду речь о прологе, который генерирует для такой функции компилятор Visual Studio. Если автор хочет тупо заимствовать у этого компилятора смещения для доступа к параметрам, то придется заимствовать и правильное значение `ebp`. Иначе получится ерунда. Разумеется, можно использовать и измененный вариант пролога, но тогда уж удосужтесь пересчитать все смещения. Либо так, либо эдак.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы не ошибиться, лучше не заниматься вычислением смещений аргументов и переменных в стеке, а переписать через имена.

Через ассемблерную вставку получается так:

```
void f_asm(int * arr, int n, int * ans)
{
    int k, s, i;
    _asm {
        mov eax, [n]
        mov dword ptr[k], eax; k
        mov dword ptr[s], 0; s
        mov dword ptr[i], 0; i
        c1 :
            mov eax, [i]
            cmp eax, [n]
            jge endc1
            mov ebx, 0; j
            c2 :

                cmp ebx, [k]
                jge endc2

                mov ecx, 0
                add ecx, [n]
                sub ecx, ebx
                dec ecx
                shl ecx, 2
                add ecx, [ans]
                mov edx, 0
                add edx, [s]
                add edx, [n]
                sub edx, ebx
                dec edx
                shl edx, 2
                add edx, [arr]
                mov eax, [edx]
                mov edx, eax
                add [ecx], edx

                inc ebx
                jmp c2
            endc2 :

            mov eax, [s]
            add eax, [n]
            mov[s], eax

            inc dword ptr[i]
            dec dword ptr[k]
            jmp c1

        endc1 :
    }
}
```

Отдельным модулем:

```
.586
.model flat, c
public _Fasm
.code

_Fasm proc uses ebx, arr: DWORD, n: DWORD, ans: DWORD
    local k: DWORD, s: DWORD, i: DWORD

    mov eax, [n]
    mov dword ptr[k], eax; k
    mov dword ptr[s], 0; s
    mov dword ptr[i], 0; i
    c1 :
        mov eax, [i]
        cmp eax, [n]
        jge endc1
        mov ebx, 0; j
        c2 :

            cmp ebx, [k]
            jge endc2

            mov ecx, 0
            add ecx, [n]
            sub ecx, ebx
            dec ecx
            shl ecx, 2
            add ecx, [ans]
            mov edx, 0
            add edx, [s]
            add edx, [n]
            sub edx, ebx
            dec edx
            shl edx, 2
            add edx, [arr]
            mov eax, [edx]
            mov edx, eax
            add [ecx], edx

            inc ebx
            jmp c2
        endc2 :

        mov eax, [s]
        add eax, [n]
        mov[s], eax

        inc dword ptr[i]
        dec dword ptr[k]
        jmp c1

    endc1 :
    ret
_Fasm endp
end
```

Под дизассемблером код функций выглядит почти идентично, отличается только незначительными деталями (порядком расположения локальных переменных в стеке, `sub     esp, 0Ch` вместо `add     esp, 0FFFFFFF4h`, `leave` вместо `mov     esp, ebp`, `pop     ebp`).